I can't edit left, right, top, or bottom despite an SVG being position:absolute
I want to put an outline on the other eyelid (with the class "other_eyelid_outline") here:


function getRandomColor() {
    const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    let color = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 's' || event.key === 'S') {
        const headColor = document.getElementById('head_color');
        headColor.setAttribute('fill', getRandomColor());

        // Optional: If eyelids need to match the head color, add this:
        const eyelids = document.getElementById('eyelids_color');
        eyelids.setAttribute('fill', headColor.getAttribute('fill'));
    }
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const pupils = document.getElementById('pupils'); // Group containing both pupils

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        const eyesSvg = document.getElementById('eyes_svg');
        const eyesBox = eyesSvg.getBoundingClientRect();

        // Approximate center of the eyes (you may need to adjust these values based on your design)
        const eyeCenterX = eyesBox.left + eyesBox.width / 2;
        const eyeCenterY = eyesBox.top + eyesBox.height / 2;

        const maxPupilMovement = 10; // Maximum movement inside the eye

        // Calculate the mouse position relative to the center of the eyes
        const mouseX = event.clientX;
        const mouseY = event.clientY;

        // Calculate the angle and distance for pupil movement
        const angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - eyeCenterY, mouseX - eyeCenterX);
        const distance = Math.min(maxPupilMovement, Math.hypot(mouseX - eyeCenterX, mouseY - eyeCenterY));

        // Calculate the new pupil positions
        const pupilX = Math.cos(angle) * distance;
        const pupilY = Math.sin(angle) * distance;

        // Apply the transformation to the pupils group (move it down based on calculated values)
        pupils.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${48.5 + pupilX}, ${29.0 + pupilY})`);
    });
});
.character {
  position: relative;
}

.guide {
  position: absolute;
}

.part {
  position: absolute;
}

.eyes {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 19px;
}

.eyesoutline {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.whole_head {
  position: absolute;
  animation: float 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.head {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 19px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.headcolor {
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -500px;
  position: relative;
}

.headoutline {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes float {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}


/* Wipe-in and wipe-out animation for the eyelid (VERTICAL wipe) */



@keyframes wipe-in-out-eyelid {
  0% {
    clip-path: inset(0 0 100% 0); /* Fully hidden from the bottom */
  }
  5% {
    clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0); /* Fully visible (wipe-in complete) */
  }
  10% {
    clip-path: inset(0 0 100% 0); /* Fully hidden again (wipe-out complete) */
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: inset(0 0 100% 0); /* Stay hidden for the rest of the duration */
 }
}



@keyframes eyelids-outlines {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  5% {
    transform: translateY(50px); /*full length of the eye.*/
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
}

.eyelid {
  fill: #ffcc66; /* Eyelid color */
  animation: wipe-in-out-eyelid 5s ease-out infinite; /* Wipe animation */
  transform-origin: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}
/* Animation for the line growing down, shrinking, and moving back up */
.eyelid_outline {
  animation: eyelids-outlines 5s ease-out infinite;
  transform-origin: center;
  position: relative;
  top:8px;
}

.other_eyelid_outline {
  position:absolute;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Character Assembly</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="player.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="guide">
        <object data="/svgs/char/shapes/30.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part body"></object>

    </div>
    
    <div class="character">

    <div class="guide">
        <object data="/svgs/char/shapes/30.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part body"></object>

    </div>

    <div class="whole_head">
        

    <div class="eyes">
        
        

<svg id="eyes_svg">
    <g transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 57.3, 26.6)">
        <path d="M26.55 -26.6 Q39.25 -26.6 48.25 -18.8 57.25 -11.0 57.25 0.0 57.25 11.0 48.25 18.8 39.25 26.6 26.55 26.6 13.85 26.6 4.85 18.8 -4.15 11.0 -4.15 0.0 -4.15 -11.0 4.85 -18.8 13.85 -26.6 26.55 -26.6 M-24.7 -12.75 Q-19.1 -6.35 -19.1 2.7 -19.1 11.75 -24.7 18.15 -30.3 24.55 -38.2 24.55 -46.1 24.55 -51.7 18.15 -57.3 11.75 -57.3 2.7 -57.3 -6.35 -51.7 -12.75 -46.1 -19.15 -38.2 -19.15 -30.3 -19.15 -24.7 -12.75" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
    </g>

    <!-- Pupils -->
    <g id="pupils" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 34.5, 7.0)">
        <path d="M-24.25 4.75 Q-26.0 6.5 -28.5 6.5 -31.0 6.5 -32.75 4.75 -34.5 3.0 -34.5 0.5 -34.5 -2.0 -32.75 -3.75 -31.0 -5.5 -28.5 -5.5 -26.0 -5.5 -24.25 -3.75 -22.5 -2.0 -22.5 0.5 -22.5 3.0 -24.25 4.75" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
        <path d="M33.15 4.95 Q31.1 7.0 28.2 7.0 25.3 7.0 23.25 4.95 21.2 2.9 21.2 0.0 21.2 -2.9 23.25 -4.95 25.3 -7.0 28.2 -7.0 31.1 -7.0 33.15 -4.95 35.2 -2.9 35.2 0.0 35.2 2.9 33.15 4.95" fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
    </g>
          <clipPath id="cut-bottom">
      <defs><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="a"><path d="M-57.3-26.6v53.2H3.839c-.02-.301-.042-.6-.06-.901-2.963-.245-5.933-.587-8.878-.643-.655-1.858-1.444-3.675-1.967-5.574-.263-.958-.582-3.19-.855-5.266-6.813-.163-3.393-1.313-.123-.97-.095-.755-.228-1.738-.274-2.133-.457-3.96-.765-7.936-1.072-11.91-.203-2.596-.417-5.192-.633-7.787-.846-10.18 3.516-15.993 8.582-17.073.037-.314.08-.628.118-.943zm52.1 40.836-.01.002.01.008v-.01z"/></clipPath></defs><path d="M26.55-26.6q12.7 0 21.7 7.8t9 18.8q0 11-9 18.8-9 7.8-21.7 7.8t-21.7-7.8q-9-7.8-9-18.8t9-18.8q9-7.8 21.7-7.8M-24.7-12.75q5.6 6.4 5.6 15.45 0 9.05-5.6 15.45-5.6 6.4-13.5 6.4t-13.5-6.4q-5.6-6.4-5.6-15.45 0-9.05 5.6-15.45 5.6-6.4 13.5-6.4t13.5 6.4" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd" style="fill:blue" clip-path="url(#a)" transform="translate(57.3 26.6)"/>
    </clipPath>
      

    <!-- Eyelids (blinking animation) -->

<g clip-path="url(#cut-bottom)">
<g class="eyelid_outline" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 66.55, 1.35)">
    <g>
    <path d="M66.55 1.4 L-66.55 1.4 -66.55 -1.35 66.55 -1.35 66.55 1.4" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.49803922" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
</g>
<g class="other_eyelid_outline">
    <path d="M66.55 1.4 L-66.55 1.4 -66.55 -1.35 66.55 -1.35 66.55 1.4" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.49803922" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
</g>
  </g>
  </g>
 <g class="eyelid"  transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 57.3, 26.6)">
    <path id="eyelids_color" d="M26.55 -26.6 Q39.25 -26.6 48.25 -18.8 57.25 -11.0 57.25 0.0 57.25 11.0 48.25 18.8 39.25 26.6 26.55 26.6 13.85 26.6 4.85 18.8 -4.15 11.0 -4.15 0.0 -4.15 -11.0 4.85 -18.8 13.85 -26.6 26.55 -26.6 M-24.7 -12.75 Q-19.1 -6.35 -19.1 2.7 -19.1 11.75 -24.7 18.15 -30.3 24.55 -38.2 24.55 -46.1 24.55 -51.7 18.15 -57.3 11.75 -57.3 2.7 -57.3 -6.35 -51.7 -12.75 -46.1 -19.15 -38.2 -19.15 -30.3 -19.15 -24.7 -12.75" fill="#ffcc66"/>

       
</g>
    
    <g id="eyesoutline" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 57.3, 26.6)">
    <path d="M-50.2 -11.05 Q-55.2 -5.35 -55.2 2.7 -55.2 10.8 -50.2 16.5 -45.25 22.2 -38.15 22.2 -31.1 22.2 -26.1 16.5 -21.15 10.8 -21.1 2.7 -21.15 -5.35 -26.1 -11.05 -31.1 -16.8 -38.15 -16.8 -45.25 -16.8 -50.2 -11.05 M-57.3 2.7 Q-57.3 -6.35 -51.7 -12.75 -46.1 -19.15 -38.2 -19.15 -30.3 -19.15 -24.7 -12.75 -19.1 -6.35 -19.1 2.7 -19.1 11.75 -24.7 18.15 -30.3 24.55 -38.2 24.55 -46.1 24.55 -51.7 18.15 -57.3 11.75 -57.3 2.7" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.49803922" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
    <path d="M26.55 -24.3 Q14.9 -24.3 6.7 -17.15 -1.55 -10.05 -1.55 0.05 -1.55 10.1 6.7 17.25 14.9 24.35 26.55 24.4 38.15 24.35 46.4 17.25 54.65 10.1 54.65 0.05 54.65 -10.05 46.4 -17.15 38.15 -24.3 26.55 -24.3 M26.55 -26.6 Q39.25 -26.6 48.25 -18.8 57.25 -11.0 57.25 0.0 57.25 11.0 48.25 18.8 39.25 26.6 26.55 26.6 13.85 26.6 4.85 18.8 -4.15 11.0 -4.15 0.0 -4.15 -11.0 4.85 -18.8 13.85 -26.6 26.55 -26.6" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.49803922" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
  </g>


</svg>


        </div>
        
        <!-- Outline SVG -->
        <div class="head">



            <svg id="head_svg">
               

    <svg id="head_shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="150" height="90">



              <g transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 75.0, 45.0)">
    <path id="head_color" d="M75.0 0.0 Q75.0 18.65 53.0 31.8 31.05 45.0 0.0 45.0 -31.05 45.0 -53.05 31.8 -75.0 18.65 -75.0 0.0 -75.0 -18.65 -53.05 -31.85 -31.05 -45.0 0.0 -45.0 31.05 -45.0 53.0 -31.85 75.0 -18.65 75.0 0.0" fill="#ffcc66" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" />
  </g>
         
        <g id="headoutline" transform="matrix(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 75.0, 45.0)">
    <path d="M53.0 -31.85 Q75.0 -18.65 75.0 0.0 75.0 18.65 53.0 31.8 31.05 45.0 0.0 45.0 -31.05 45.0 -53.05 31.8 -75.0 18.65 -75.0 0.0 -75.0 -18.65 -53.05 -31.85 -31.05 -45.0 0.0 -45.0 31.05 -45.0 53.0 -31.85 M51.05 -29.9 Q29.9 -42.25 0.0 -42.25 -29.9 -42.25 -51.05 -29.9 -72.2 -17.5 -72.2 0.0 -72.2 17.5 -51.05 29.85 -29.9 42.25 0.0 42.25 29.9 42.25 51.05 29.85 72.2 17.5 72.2 0.0 72.2 -17.5 51.05 -29.9" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.49803922" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
  </g>

  </svg>
</svg>
</div>



</div>
      <!--  <object data="body.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part body"></object>
        <object data="leftarms.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part arms"></object>
        <object data="rightarms.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part arms"></object>
        <object data="leftlegs.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part legs"></object>
        <object data="rightlegs.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="part legs"></object>-->
    </div> 

    <script src="player.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



I went into my browser's dev tools to check if they would allow me to move the very outside margins (you know, the top, bottom, left, right attribute), but I couldn't see them in the preview layer:

So basically, that other_eyelid_outline can float up and down with the left eyelid outline, but the problem is that I cannot edit top, bottom, etc on the other_eyelid_outline despite its position being absolute. What should I change in order to move that eyelid around?

Similar to this existing post Absolute positioning of svg element not working. You may find its solution helpful

You can't apply properties like top,left, bottom,right to SVG (child) elements. You can use transform translate – but this may override previous transformations. Frankly, your current structure stacking 2 separate svgs on top of each other rather complicates the positioning. Couldn't you just merge head and eyes into a single SVG?
